# ExoPlayer Google Library Integration

Tags: android, video, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to integrate **Exoplayer** for Loading List of Videos and generate preview of it.

for that i refers github repository Library. and integration steps, from 
[Mayur thakur Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848293/google-exoplayer-guide)

but i am confused with Two Library conflict 
`com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory`
`androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory`

and i am unable to resolve it 
as

```
  DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
  AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory factory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
```

**MediaSource** cannot be applied of **Factory** from  **com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter**

i am sharing some line of code here do check

```
                    defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
                    factory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
                    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(factory);
                    loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
                    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance((Context)mContext, trackSelector, loadControl);
                    mVideo.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
                    DefaultBandwidthMeter dBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
                    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory((Context)mContext,
                            Util.getUserAgent((Context)mContext, "com.exoplayerdemo"), dBandwidthMeter);
                    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri,dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null); 
                    mVideo.getPlayer().prepare(mediaSource);
```

if any one knows about this conflict and resolved it let me know

Thanks

Comment: You can use `AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()` without `defaultBandwidthMeter` parameter.

Comment: ```AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()```  mainly Factory()  is not accessible and create conflict between both this library.